# IIS7.5 Application Initialisation and Web-gardens

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web-garden

While using IIS7.5 and the [Application Initialisation](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) module it's possible to have your web application always be running and also have a custom method notified to warm up your cache etc.  Is it possible for this feature to work in web-garden mode?

i.e. having multiple worker-processes ready to process requests.

I have added the required xml to allow a the worker-process to be initialised, but this only results in a single worker-process ready to receive requests.

```
    <applicationPools>
        <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
    </applicationPools>
```

Is there anyway to have multiple worker-processes all ready to receive?